# Execute flyway:migrate using maven on a sub module

Tags: maven-plugin, flyway

We have below maven structure for

```
main
    |
    pom.xml
    web
       |
       pom.xml
    persistance
              |
              pom.xml
    Service
           |
           pom.xml
```

We run "mvn clean install" inside the main folder and i have the flyway plugin in my 'web' module. When i do "mvn clean install flyway:migrate" on the web module, flyway runs fine. But when i try to do the same on main module it gives me error :

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'flyway' in the current project and
>   in the pl ugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the rep ositories [local
>   (C:\Users\balajig.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.
>   apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Its obvious that when i do "mvn clean install" on my main module flyway doesn't get invoked and placing configuration inside the 'compile' execution phase is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

A maven plugin only runs unprefixed in a project/module where it has been defined. Your main pom does not define it, so it is normal Maven cannot resolve it.